# What is a software prefetcher (processor setting)?

Tags: central-processing-unit, bios, drac

Configuring the CPU(s) of a DELL Server (via iDrac) I have run accross the term `software prefetcher`.

[image]

I have an idea that prefetching is to "fetch" in advance data from the memory in to the CPUs' cache(s). I understand that this can be realized via Hardware. I do not understand the "software" here. What would switching enabled/disabled for the "Software Prefetcher" change?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading the manual for your server model. For example, according to this article:

https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-uk/000176921/bios-characterization-for-hpc-with-intel-cascade-lake-processors?lwp=rt

> Software Prefetcher: [...] when set enabled, the processor will prefetch extra cache line for every memory request.